# Is there a word meaning "the other side to compare against"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word in English that means "something to compare against", or "the other side of the compare". Is there a single word for this?

Comment: *Comparand* is the term used in technical contexts for the objects being compared, similarly to *operand*.

Comment: @Kris thanks, I think I was looking for this word after all!

Comment: This question *really* deserves more credit than it's getting!

Comment: @Kris You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard against which something is compared is a ***comparator***.

> **comparator** *noun*
>   ...
>   something used as a standard for comparison:
>   *even taking the most favourable comparator the company is about 20 per cent higher*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comparator)

Comment: how do I know this is not a `verb` but a `noun`? it *sounds like* it could be used as a `verb`. it would make use to me if the word I use could be seen clearly as a noun. (I would use it in a programming context where an arbitrary name could either mean a function or a data.)

Comment: Words ending *-or* are in general agent nouns. *Compare* is the verb. *Comparator* is something used in the act of comparing.

Comment: @naxa How would you ascertain whether _any_ English word you're unfamiliar with is a noun / verb ... - or indeed, whether it is intercategorially polysemous (occurs in different constructions as a noun / verb / ...)? Admittedly, I had to go beyond my usual favourites at freedictionary.com to see the general usage Andrew mentions; oxforddictionaries has: _comparator_ [(2)]  something used as a standard for comparison - but all the dictionaries I looked at say it's a noun (and never anything else).

Comment: Comparator is "a device for comparing a measurable property or thing with a reference or standard." or the standard itself.

Comment: @Kris Yes: but I answered the question with the relevant part of the definition, indicated an omission (of data which is not relevant) and gave a link to the complete version. Why the downvote?

Comment: This term is not used in the sense of one of the objects being compared. "even taking the most favourable comparator the company is about 20 per cent higher" uses *comparator* in the sense of *by the highest/lowest standard* -- apparently you misunderstood the term.

Comment: Yes it is. If you compare against a standard, the standard is the comparator. What you compare something against is the comparator (the standard you are measuring against).

Comment: What you compare something to is the *comparand*.  The *comparator* is what does the comparing.

Comment: @HotLicks I backed up my answer with a reputable citation.

Answer (score 5):

> [**Comparand**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparand) is the term used in technical contexts for the objects being
>   compared, similarly to operand. – Kris May 3 '13 at 12:03

It means

> (linguistics, computing) A thing to which something is compared.

[Wiktionary]

*Comparator*, on the other hand, is the thing (device or algorithm) that performs the comparison.

Comment: I've just edited your answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

In a scientific context, this could be a **Control**.

> A scientific control is an experiment or observation designed to minimize the effects of variables other than the independent variable.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control) This increases the reliability of the results, often through **a comparison between control measurements and the other measurements**. Scientific controls are a part of the scientific method. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control)

In literature, you could use the word **Foil**

> In fiction, a foil is a character who **contrasts with another character** (usually the protagonist) **in order to highlight particular qualities** of the other character. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(literature))

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, a ***benchmark*** may work too.

ODO:

> **[benchmark](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/benchmark)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A standard or point of reference against which things may be compared.
>
> ‘the pay settlement will set a benchmark for other employers and
>   workers’
>
> ‘There is no question that this new plant has set new standards in
>   every aspect and will unquestionably become a benchmark for future
>   factories in the future.’